# What is the complexity of finding a maximum size independent set in self-Complementary graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

A self-complementary graph is isomorphic to its (edge) complement. My question is whether finding a maximum cardinality independent set remains hard on this class of graphs. It is known that for some sub-classes of self-complementary graphs the problem becomes in P but I couldn't find anything regarding the more general question.

Thanks!